# BufferedReader - read all characters (not lines)

Tags: java, bufferedreader

How to read all available characters to a `String` using `BufferedReader`?

I have a `Socket` from which I want to read data, when available, and store it in a `String`. The thing is, I can't use `readLine` because the data I receive not always contains a newline or caret return, and `readLine` blocks thread until it can read a full line. How to use `read` instead?

```
thread = new Thread(() ->
    {
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

             while(true) 
             {
                if (in.ready())
                {
                    String someString = // ? read available data
                    delegate.didReadData(this, someString);
                }
             }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            delegate.didDropSocket(this);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

**edit**
1. delegate doesn't care how long the string is, it just needs to handle any hada that arrives via socket - and full contents of it
2. I don't need to cut data into chunks - I want to read everyhing that arrives
3. Yes, I have an infinite loop for I need to stay connected to the socket and listen for data until client drops the connection - when I get an `IOException`. I use a separate thread for socket because there will be much more sockets to listen to.

Comment: This just isn't a viable approach. Your `while(true)` and `if(ready)` is a poor and inefficient emulation of NIO selector. It's either a thread blocking on `read(byte[] buffer)` (note that this adds complexity if using a multibyte encoding like `UTF-8`), or NIO, as it seems there's no protocol you're following. You can also describe the actual end result you're trying to achieve, so we can suggest you proper solutions. Currently you're off the mark.

Comment: I don't know what NIO is, I'm new to Java and this is a side project. In general what I'm trying to do: i want to listen to any client sockets that try to connect to my program, and when they connect, I want to read and handle any data that arrives. The application will feature a GUI so reading from sockets can't block main thread. Any partucular reason why my approach isn't viable? Like I said, I'm new to Java

Comment: Because the way sockets work is you say "I want to read data", and then at some point you get some bytes and then you do something with those bytes. Your code is trying to do a similar thing but with text. When you're working with text it's easy to have a line based protocol, but you're trying to do something different. It looks like you probably want the block on `read(byte[] buf)` approach, then convert those to chars as they arrive. Blocking is not an issue, that's why you use a thread for socket communication in the first place. If you are new to Java, it **is** going to be complicated.

Comment: Ok, I see in documentation that Reader's read(char[] cbuf) is a blocking call and since in my case every socket uses separate thread, what will work great. Can you give me an example on how to use that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to always explicitly specify which encoding you're using, you don't need to check before reading, and of course you have to keep track of how much you've read and whether the other end has closed the connection.

Exception handling and closing of resources is omitted. Buffer size can be increased if necessary. Otherwise this is a pretty idiomatic read-loop.

```
out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
char[] buf = new char[4096];
int size = 0;
while((size = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    String someString = new String(buf, 0, size);
    delegate.didReadData(this, someString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader#readLine(0)` [treats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) '\n', '\r', and "\r\n" as line-separators. This behaviour cannot be changed, so as you say, we need to use one of the two overloads of `read` instead.

What does `delegate` need? Does it care how long `someString` is? Do you need to 'chunk' the data you read from `in`? Are you sure that `String` is appropriate?

I suspect that you want the [read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read-char:A-int-int-) method.

Assuming you don't *need* to read one char at a time, you'll get better performance using that chunk-at-a-time overload of `read`, than using the one-char-at-a-time overload.

Also, you have an infinite loop. Even when `ready` returns false, your code won't terminate, as you never leave your `while(true)` loop.

Or is the intent here to have the thread constantly check for more data, without end? I'm not familiar enough with the Java standard library to give details, but I'm confident there's a better way to do it than to have a thread run one of your cores at 100% load, checking for additional data. The simple hack would be to add a `sleep` call, but I'm sure there's a better way, perhaps involving the `Stream` class.

Comment: See edit for answers to the questions. How do I use read read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) to read all the contents of the buffer at once?

Comment: I wrote up a long response, and then noticed - I think you want the `StringWriter` class, not `BufferedReader`.

The `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` classes do not expose their internal buffers - there's no way to dump the content to a String.